# qemu-system-x86_64 грузит CPU на 100%

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, qemu

Есть VPS сервер с Ubuntu 18.04.5.

На сервере лежат два .vhdx файла (виртуальные диски созданные под Windows) смонтированные на самой Ubuntu посредством libguestfs-tools.  Сами .vhdx файлы весят >100 Гб, в смонтированном виде содержат в себе несколько десятков миллионов мелких файлов.

Проблема в том, что как только я монтирую эти .vhdx файлы в системе, появляется процесс qemu-system-x86_64, который начинает грузить процессор под 100% и через несколько часов сервер виснет.

Через htop я вижу что он как то взаимодействует с этими .vhdx файлами. Если убить процесс - диски размонтируются.

ps axww | grep qemu выдает следующее:

```
1060 ?        Sl   128:05 /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -global virtio-blk-pci.scsi=off -enable-fips -nodefaults -display none -machine accel=kvm:tcg -m 500 -no-reboot -rtc driftfix=slew -no-hpet -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=discard -kernel /var/tmp/.guestfs-0/appliance.d/kernel -initrd /var/tmp/.guestfs-0/appliance.d/initrd -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0 -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi -drive file=/home/admin/web/mydomain.com/public_html/_vhdx_location/file0001.vhdx,cache=writeback,id=hd0,if=none -device scsi-hd,drive=hd0 -drive file=/var/tmp/.guestfs-0/appliance.d/root,snapshot=on,id=appliance,cache=unsafe,if=none,format=raw -device scsi-hd,drive=appliance -device virtio-serial-pci -serial stdio -chardev socket,path=/tmp/libguestfsiw3hiv/guestfsd.sock,id=channel0 -device virtserialport,chardev=channel0,name=org.libguestfs.channel.0 -append panic=1 console=ttyS0 edd=off udevtimeout=6000 udev.event-timeout=6000 no_timer_check lpj=11200000 printk.time=1 cgroup_disable=memory usbcore.nousb cryptomgr.notests tsc=reliable 8250.nr_uarts=1 root=/dev/sdb selinux=0 quiet TERM=unknown
     
1104 ?        Sl   527:50 /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -global virtio-blk-pci.scsi=off -enable-fips -nodefaults -display none -machine accel=kvm:tcg -m 500 -no-reboot -rtc driftfix=slew -no-hpet -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=discard -kernel /var/tmp/.guestfs-0/appliance.d/kernel -initrd /var/tmp/.guestfs-0/appliance.d/initrd -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0 -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi -drive file=/home/admin/web/mydomain.com/public_html/__vhdx_location_2/file0002.vhdx,cache=writeback,id=hd0,if=none -device scsi-hd,drive=hd0 -drive file=/var/tmp/.guestfs-0/appliance.d/root,snapshot=on,id=appliance,cache=unsafe,if=none,format=raw -device scsi-hd,drive=appliance -device virtio-serial-pci -serial stdio -chardev socket,path=/tmp/libguestfsf5opDn/guestfsd.sock,id=channel0 -device virtserialport,chardev=channel0,name=org.libguestfs.channel.0 -append panic=1 console=ttyS0 edd=off udevtimeout=6000 udev.event-timeout=6000 no_timer_check lpj=11200000 printk.time=1 cgroup_disable=memory usbcore.nousb cryptomgr.notests tsc=reliable 8250.nr_uarts=1 root=/dev/sdb selinux=0 quiet TERM=unknown
1703 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep qemu
```

Возможно надо как то изменить параметры этого qemu?

Comment: ну, например, у вас может быть не включена в bios виртуализация. проверьте: `$ grep -o "vmx\|svm" /proc/cpuinfo`. если команда ничего не выведет — значит не включена.

Comment: да, ничего не вывела команда. А каким образом не включенная виртуализация в bios-е может грузить процессор? мне не понятно. Ведь если не монтировать эти .vhdx файлы в системе - то сервер функционирует нормально и не грузит CPU

Comment: вместо отсутствующей виртуализации qemu использует значительно более медленную эмуляцию. а вот зачем там у вас вообще используется qemu — это видно только вам.